# Array not saving user input in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is what I have so far, but the array is not saving the first value if the user enters 2 or more car types. If I remove the car.get_ methods the program runs fine without saving the users input. Is there a method I am missing?

```
class Cars

    def set_make(make)
    end

    def set_model(model)
    end

    def set_year(year)
    end

    array_of_cars = Array.new 

  print "How many cars do you want to create? "
  num_cars = gets.to_i
  puts 

  for i in 1.. num_cars
    puts
    print "Enter make for car #{i}: "
    make = gets.chomp

    print "Enter model for car #{i}: "
    model = gets.chomp

    print "Enter year of car #{i}: "
    year = gets.to_i

    c = Car.new

    c.set_make(make)
    c.set_model(model)
    c.set_year(year)

    array_of_cars << c
  end 

    puts
    puts "You have the following cars: " 

  for car in array_of_cars 
    print "#{car.get_year} #{car.get_make} #{car.get_model}"
  end
end
```

Comment: please can you verify the code you pasted? Is that script defined inside the Car class?

Comment: I don't know if I have to keep the script, within the car class but currently it is.

Comment: Actually there are a bunch of problems with this code from an organization stand point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the primary issue is that you calling the `Car.new` where the `Car` class is defined. You should not have an array of cars in the car class. You could try creating a  `Dealership` class that has an array of cars then you could do something like this

```
class Dealership

  attr_accessor :car_lot

  def initialize
    @car_lot = []
  end

  def add_car(car)
    @car_lot << car
  end
end
crazy_carls = Dealership.new
car1 = Car.new(make, model, year)

crazy_carls.add_car(car1)
crazy_carls.car_lot.each do |car
  print "#{car.get_year} #{car.get_make} #{car.get_model}"
end
```

You need to refactor the car class a good deal first though, look into how to use the [initialize](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/objinitialization.html) method, [attr_accessor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor), and [instance variables](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/instancevars.html).

Comment: When running this code it says there is an uninitialized constant for Cars::car on line 33